# WPF TextBox doesn't allow symbols

Tags: c#, wpf

i had created a wpf textbox and i generate a KeyDown event for that textbox to allow only alphanumeric,space,backspace,'-' to acheive that i used following code

```
private void txtCompanyName_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
   e.Handled = !(char.IsLetterOrDigit((char)KeyInterop.VirtualKeyFromKey(e.Key)) || (char)KeyInterop.VirtualKeyFromKey(e.Key) == (char)Keys.Back || (char)KeyInterop.VirtualKeyFromKey(e.Key) == (char)Keys.Space || (char)KeyInterop.VirtualKeyFromKey(e.Key) == '-');
}
```

but it allows the symbols too in the textbox. how could i resolve this problem.sorry for my bad english. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use `PreviewKeyDown` event instead of `KeyDown` event. It will not allow keydown event to fire if handled. In order to achieve the full functionality you should also put same logic for  `textBox.PreviewTextInput` also

Answer (score 1):

I would agree with @nit, but add that you could also use the following *as well*:

```
textBox.PreviewTextInput = new TextCompositionEventHandler((s, e) => e.Handled = 
    !e.Text.All(c => Char.IsNumber(c) && c != ' '));
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, created an attached behavior that can be reused throughout your application :)

Example:

USAGE:

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" attachedBehaviors:TextBoxBehaviors.AlphaNumericOnly="True" Text="{Binding someProp}">
```

CODE:

```
public static class TextBoxBehaviors
{

public static readonly DependencyProperty AlphaNumericOnlyProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
  "AlphaNumericOnly", typeof(bool), typeof(TextBoxBehaviors), new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnAlphaNumericOnlyChanged));

static void OnAlphaNumericOnlyChanged(DependencyObject depObj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
  var tBox = (TextBox)depObj;

  if ((bool)e.NewValue)
  {
    tBox.PreviewTextInput += tBox_PreviewTextInput;
  }
  else
  {
    tBox.PreviewTextInput -= tBox_PreviewTextInput;
  }
}

static void tBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, System.Windows.Input.TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
  // Filter out non-alphanumeric text input
  foreach (char c in e.Text)
  {
    if (AlphaNumericPattern.IsMatch(c.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)))
    {
      e.Handled = true;
      break;
    }
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check if capslock is enabled or one of the shift-keys is pressed (e.g. `Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftShift);`) and if this is the case, you just allow space and back:

```
if (condition)
    e.Handled = e.Key == Key.Back || e.Key == Key.Space;
```

Also i would recommend you using the TextChanged-event, because it also gets fired if you paste something in the `TextBox`.